# Locating landfall point of cyclone using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, interpolation

On 12.12.2016 Severe Cyclone Storm "VARADHA" crossed Chennai coast.  Nungambakkam [13 Deg 04min 04 sec N/80 Deg 14 Min 44 sec]is 4.8km away from coast.  At 15.33 hrs IST it recorded 974.8hPa pressure and winds were almost calm [0.4knots]

At airport Meenambakkam the pressure is 976.3hPa and it is 10.3 km away from coast.  Varada would have crossed in between these location.

I want to interpolate pressure and wish to find the exact location of crossing with central pressure.

Which interpolation technique do I have to use?

Answer (score 3):

A nice comparative analysis of different methods can be found [here](https://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0704/files/interpolating.pdf). Because pressure is continuous, it would be effective to use the Spline method.

From the text:

> **Spline**
>  Spline estimates values using a mathematical
>   function that minimizes  overall surface curvature. This results in a
>   smooth surface that passes  exactly through the input points.
>   Conceptually, it is like bending a sheet  of rubber so that it passes
>   through the points while minimizing the total  curvature of the
>   surface. **It can predict ridges and valleys in the data and  is the
>   best method for representing the smoothly varying surfaces of
>   phenomena such as temperature.**